# How to profile memory of a spring boot webapp running on cloud foundry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, memory-profiling

I have a Spring boot application running on internal cloud foundry space.
I want to monitor the Stack and Heap memory of this web app, in order to find a StackOverflow exception originating from code.

What could be the best way to profile the application.

Answer (score 6):

- https://content.pivotal.io/blog/new-cloud-foundry-java-buildpack-improves-developer-diagnostic-tools
- https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-Remotely-Debug-Java-Applications-on-Cloud-Foundry

## 1. Run your app with JMX settings

- To test profiling on your local machine run `theapp` with the following JMX configuration and then go to the last step **"3. VisualVM configuration"**:

  ```
  java \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -jar theapp.jar ...
  ```
- To pass the JMX configuration to `theapp` in CF use the `JBP_CONFIG_JMX` environment variable (or `JAVA_OPTS` with params as above), `manifest.yml`:

  ```
  applications:
    - name: theapp
      buildpack: java_buildpack
      env:
        JBP_CONFIG_JMX: "{enabled: true, port: 9999}"
        # JAVA_OPTS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  ```

### 2. Create SSH tunnel to theapp's container

```
cf ssh -N -T -L 9999:localhost:9999 theapp
```

### 3. VisualVM configuration

- Download [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
- Run VisualVM: `visualvm --jdkhome "$JAVA_HOME"`
- Add JMX connection: `localhost:9999`

---

---

#### You can also create SSH tunnel using [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/)

- Retrieve and display theapp's guid:

  ```sh
  cf app theapp --guid
  # example: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
  ```
- Get a one time password for ssh clients:

  ```sh
  cf ssh-code
  # example: PolSkAjEzyKtrUdnA
  ```
- Create PuTTY SSH connection:

  - hostname: `theapp.your.cloud`
  - port: `2222`
  - username: `cf:<app-guid>/<app-instance-index>@ssh.your.cloud`

    - example: `cf:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/0@ssh.your.cloud`
  - password: `<ssh-code>`

    - example: `PolSkAjEzyKtrUdnA`
  - connection/ssh/tunnels/:

    - source port: `9999`
    - destination: `127.0.0.1:9999`

Answer (score 1):

In case you have ssh access enabled in your cloudfoundry installation, you can use JMX or Yourkit Profiler to do this.

Here are some links:

- https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/just-released-java-buildpack-4-0/
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-your_kit_profiler.md
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-jmx.md

Comment: There is also the Java Memory Assistant in the Java buildpack.  It can be used to trigger heap dumps under certain conditions, like when a certain threshold is hit. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_memory_assistant.md and the kill agent which will do the same when there is an OOME.